# Qualcomm takes over CSR and now my Bluetooth Programming Interface is missing?

Tags: bluetooth, core-bluetooth, csr, qualcomm

Does anybody here know anything about what Qualcomm has done to the Bluetooth chips they acquired after they purchased CSR.  My project has been using the CSR8675 for many years.  This chip has a USB Configuration/Interface/set of Endpoints whose Class is Wireless Controller code (E0h) and Subclass is 'Bluetooth Programming Interface' (01h).

Now, we are considering going to a Qualcomm IC in the QCC514x line.  The way I read Qualcomm's website it indicates that the QCC5141 will work with BlueSuite 3.3.  One of the tools in BlueSuite 3.3 is BTCLI.EXE, a command line tool for testing the bluetooth capabilities of the chip.

Qualcomm has several documents on how to setup and configure BlueSuite 3.3 but, after hours and hours of trying many different things, I cannot get the BTCLI.EXE to communicate with the development board we purchased for evaluating the QCC5141.

When I plug this board into my PC, Windows recognizes 2 USB devices from it, a 'Qualcomm Hub Device' and a 'Qualcomm Debug Interface'.  According to the docs for BTCLI, once you have the 'Qualcomm Debug Interface' device available, all you have to do is type 'btcli.exe usbdbg -qhci' and it should connect and you're in business.  However, every time I do this I get the same response:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\QTIL\BlueSuite 3.3.18>btcli usbdbg -qhci
btcli, version 3.3.18.2017 Release
Copyright (c) 2001-2023 Qualcomm Technologies International, Ltd.
All Rights Reserved.
Qualcomm Technologies International, Ltd. Confidential and Proprietary.

==============================================================================
ERROR: Timeout waiting for TTP connect response
==============================================================================
TTP via usbdbg not established
```

I have tried this on multiple development boards and I get the same thing.  I have tried this on Windows 10 & 11 and I get the same thing.

Does anyone have any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?  Has Qualcomm disabled the Bluetooth Programming interface?

Thanks so much in advance!

I tried installing the software on Windows 10 & 11.
I always installed as an Administrator.
I unlocked the 'Qualcomm Debug Interface' USB device and see it in Windows Device Manager.